# dump XML::LibXML elements

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I would like to dump the xml doc tree similar to the way perl data types can be dumped.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($foo);
```

Recursivly dumps the structure contained by `$foo` (even if there are cyclic dependencies).

However

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($filename);
my @nodes  = $doc->findnodes($path);
foreach(@nodes)
{
    print Dumper($_);
}
```

just prints things like

```
$VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = 46232224)}, 'XML::LibXML::Element' );
```

I would like to get a tree of LibXML - elements that represents the XML-structure.

Comment: Those objects aren't implemented in Perl. You're probably dealing with a C data structure.

Comment: There's no such thing. XML::LibXML is a wrapper around `libxml2`, which is a C library, so the internal representation is not  Perl readable.

Comment: For consistency, shouldn't your name be "vlad_zepesch"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `serialize` method of [`LibXML::Node`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod):

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($filename);
my @nodes  = $doc->findnodes($path);
foreach my $node (@nodes)
{
    print $node->serialize;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Walk the tree to convert the opaque structure into a dumpable one.

```
use XML::LibXML qw(:libxml);
use Data::Visitor::Callback qw();

my $v = Data::Visitor::Callback->new(
    'XML::LibXML::Text' => sub {
        my ($v, $node) = @_;
        return ($node->nodeValue =~ qr/\S/)
            ? {
                n => $node->nodeName,
                t => $node->nodeType,
                v => $node->nodeValue,
            }
            : (); # skip whitespace text nodes
    },
    'XML::LibXML::Element' => sub {
        my ($v, $node) = @_;
        return {
            c => [grep $_, $v->visit($node->childNodes)],
            n => $node->nodeName,
            t => $node->nodeType,
        };
    },
);

use DDP; p $v->visit(
    XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('foo.xml')->findnodes('/*')
);
```